# How to make Edittext can be marked only programmatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, clickable, focusable

I wanna have an `EditText` which can be updated only **programmatically**. When I click on it, I will not be able to enter anything, but when I click the button with `requestFocus` to this `EditText` I want to have that option.

I tried `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`, but in this case, I can't use `EditText` when I click button either.

Any ideas?

Comment: `I wanna have an EditText which can be updated only programmatically.` Use a TextView, then.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable or disable the EditText.

```
android:enabled="false"
```

And when you click on your button, you have to do :

```
myEditText.setEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attributes of EditText `android:enabled="false"` and in your button event handler use `((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext)).setEnabled(true);` if id of EditText is `edittext`.